# How to get value from two json files in angularjs

Tags: json, angularjs

Can anyone please help to solve my problems.

in angular js. I have below json and HTML file

test.json

```
{
"list": [
{
    "id": 1,
    "Name": "Name 1"
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "Name": "Name 2"
}
]
}
```

array.json

```
{
    "list": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "time": [
        {
            "time1": "10.00am",
            "time2": "10.10am",
            "time3": "10.20am",
            "time4": "10.30am"
        }
        ]
    }
```

I need output like below

```
id: 1
Name: Name1
time: 10.00am, 10.10am, 10.20am, 10.30am

id: 1
Name: Name1
time: 10.00am, 10.10am
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Well, what have you tried so far? Show us some code, and tell us where you problem is.

Comment: it's not even clear why there are two .json files here with almost identical structure and data.  The second file (array.json) doesn't have enough properties to achieve the output you describe.

Answer (score 0):

### HTML

```
<div class="abc" ng-repeat="data in datas[0].list">
    ID:{{data.id}}<br>
    Name:{{data.Name}}<br>
    Time:
        <ANY ng-repeat="times in data.time[0]">
            {{times}}
        </ANY>
    <hr>
</div>
```

### Controller

```
$scope.datas=[{
"list": [
{
    "id": 1,
    "Name": "Name 1",
    "time": [
    {
        "time1": "10.00am",
        "time2": "10.10am",
        "time3": "10.20am",
        "time4": "10.30am"
    }
    ]
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "Name": "Name 2",
    "time": [
    {
        "time1": "10.00am",
        "time2": "10.10am"
    }
    ]
}
]
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-repeat in your case something link below.

```
 <span ng-repeat="list in myList">
  Id : {{list.id}}<br/>
  Name : {{list.Name}}<br/>
    <span ng-repeat="tm in times | filter:{id: list.id}">
      Time : <span ng-repeat="tim in tm.time">
      <span ng-repeat="t in tim">
        {{t}}{{$last ? '' : ', '}}
        <span>
      </span>    
    </span><br/>
  </span>
```

Here is the working pen for you.

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RWgPvv)

Comment: Have updated my codepen to reflect your changes. You have to use filter for inside array based on the parent id.

Comment: Thanks man,
How to get those values if its in two JSON files?
test.json
array.JSOn

Comment: This will help you in that case http://plnkr.co/edit/Lh9sYyTRjWziN1ZEg29t?p=preview.

Comment: I don't see any demo in this. Is this link correct?

Comment: Its a working example of how you can read data from text files. You have to make two separate calls to read json data from file and assign it to respective scope variables

Comment: Can you please mark this answer as a answered to help other people understand that it is solved.